# How to get the numbers alone from list using regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

How to get the numbers alone from list using regex?

```
import re

l=[["123abc","456"],["lmnop0987"]]
list_1=[]
for i,string in enumerate(l):
   if i == 0 :
     for j in string:
       if re.findall(r"[0-9]", j):
               list_1.append(j) 
 print(list_1)
```

> Expected Result:

```
    ['123','456']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending `j` to `list_1`, but I think you want to append the result of [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to list_1:

```
l=[["123abc","456"],["lmnop0987"]]
list_1=[]
for i,string in enumerate(l):
    if i == 0 :
        for j in string:
            list_1.append(re.findall(r'[0-9]+', j)[0])
print(list_1)
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Sip4N8)

Note to repeat matching the digits 1+ times `[0-9]+` using a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) `+`

Result

```
['123', '456']
```